# Problem with Dreamweaver CS5 live view and browsers view

Tags: php, html, css, dreamweaver

Greeting,
I have an image that I sliced it with Fireworks then I export it to html.
I opened the HTML with Dreamweaver and I saved the file to php and it works OK. I replaced few images with HTML input tags and html buttons and set their width and height with css with same size as the original image and I placed them in same place exactly in the live view in Dreamweaver the page looks perfect but when I few it in Firefox or IE the looks look messy and the sizes of the input fields and the buttons look lager.
Please look at my code and advice me how to solve the problem

I'm going to put my original and the modified one to compare.

Original Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>habib_contact_us.jpg</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">td img {display: block;}</style>
<!--Fireworks CS5 Dreamweaver CS5 target.  Created Fri Jul 29 11:34:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 2011-->
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="970">
<!-- fwtable fwsrc="habib_contact_us_working_file.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="habib_contact_us.jpg" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "842372334" fwnested="0" -->
  <tr>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="61" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="208" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="189" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="43" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="44" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="29" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="45" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="42" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="15" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="221" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="73" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td colspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r1_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r1_c1.jpg" width="970" height="52" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r1_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="52" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="7" colspan="3"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c1.jpg" width="458" height="261" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c4.jpg" width="203" height="26" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c9" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c9.jpg" width="15" height="344" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c9" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="8"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c10" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c10.jpg" width="221" height="278" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c10" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c11" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c11.jpg" width="73" height="344" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c11" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="26" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r3_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r3_c4.jpg" width="203" height="3" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r3_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r4_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r4_c4.jpg" width="203" height="25" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r4_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="25" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r5_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r5_c4.jpg" width="203" height="3" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r5_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r6_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r6_c4.jpg" width="203" height="23" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r6_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="23" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r7_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r7_c4.jpg" width="203" height="6" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r7_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r8_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r8_c4.jpg" width="203" height="192" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r8_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="175" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c1.jpg" width="61" height="83" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c2" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c2.jpg" width="208" height="23" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c2" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c3" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c3.jpg" width="189" height="83" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c3" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r10_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r10_c4.jpg" width="203" height="6" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r10_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="habib_contact_us_r10_c10" src="images/habib_contact_us_r10_c10.jpg" width="221" height="66" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r10_c10" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c2" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c2.jpg" width="208" height="60" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c2" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c4.jpg" width="43" height="60" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c5" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c5.jpg" width="44" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c5" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c6" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c6.jpg" width="29" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c6" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c7" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c7.jpg" width="45" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c7" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c8" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c8.jpg" width="42" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c8" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="22" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r12_c5" src="images/habib_contact_us_r12_c5.jpg" width="160" height="38" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r12_c5" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="38" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Modified Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
td img {
display: block;
}

#txtEmail {
    height: 25px;
    width: 203px;
}

#txtName {
    height: 26px;
    width: 203px;
}

#txtSubject {

    height: 23px;
    width: 203px;

}

#txtMsg {
    height: 192px;
    width: 203px;
}

#btnSubmit {
    height: 22px;
    width: 44px;
}   

#btnClear {
    height: 22px;
    width: 45px;
}   



</style>
<!--Fireworks CS5 Dreamweaver CS5 target.  Created Fri Jul 29 11:34:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 2011-->
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">



<table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="970" id="table">
  <!-- fwtable fwsrc="habib_contact_us_working_file.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="habib_contact_us.jpg" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "842372334" fwnested="0" -->
  <tr>

<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="61" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="208" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="189" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="43" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="44" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="29" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="45" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="42" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="15" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="221" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="73" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r1_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r1_c1.jpg" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r1_c1" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="52" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="7" colspan="3"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c1.jpg" width="458" height="261" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c1" alt="" /></td>
    <td colspan="5">


  <?php /*?><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c4.jpg" width="203" height="26" border="0"               id="habib_contact_us_r2_c4" alt="" />
    <?php */?>

    <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName"  />

    </td>
    <td rowspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c9" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c9.jpg" width="15" height="344" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c9" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="8"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c10" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c10.jpg" width="221" height="278" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c10" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="11"><img name="habib_contact_us_r2_c11" src="images/habib_contact_us_r2_c11.jpg" width="73" height="344" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r2_c11" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="26" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r3_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r3_c4.jpg" width="203" height="3" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r3_c4" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" >

  <?php /*?>  <img name="habib_contact_us_r4_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r4_c4.jpg" width="203" height="25" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r4_c4" alt="" /><?php */?>


    <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail"  />




    </td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="25" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r5_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r5_c4.jpg" width="203" height="3" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r5_c4" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <?php /*?><img name="habib_contact_us_r6_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r6_c4.jpg" width="203" height="23" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r6_c4" alt="" /><?php */?>
    <input type="text" name="txtSubject" id="txtSubject"  />


    </td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="23" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r7_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r7_c4.jpg" width="203" height="6" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r7_c4" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="5">
    <?php /*?><img name="habib_contact_us_r8_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r8_c4.jpg" width="203" height="192" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r8_c4" alt="" /><?php */?>

     <textarea name="txtMsg" cols="" rows=""  id="txtMsg"></textarea>


    </td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="175" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c1" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c1.jpg" width="61" height="83" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c1" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c2" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c2.jpg" width="208" height="23" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c2" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r9_c3" src="images/habib_contact_us_r9_c3.jpg" width="189" height="83" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r9_c3" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><img name="habib_contact_us_r10_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r10_c4.jpg" width="203" height="6" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r10_c4" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><img name="habib_contact_us_r10_c10" src="images/habib_contact_us_r10_c10.jpg" width="221" height="66" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r10_c10" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c2" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c2.jpg" width="208" height="60" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c2" alt="" /></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c4" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c4.jpg" width="43" height="60" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c4" alt="" /></td>
    <td>

   <?php /*?> <img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c5" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c5.jpg" width="44" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c5" alt="" /><?php */?>
    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" id="btnSubmit"/>

    </td>
    <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c6" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c6.jpg" width="29" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c6" alt="" /></td>
    <td>
    <?php /*?><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c7" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c7.jpg" width="45" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c7" alt="" /><?php */?>

    <input name="btnClear" type="reset" value="Clear" id="btnClear" />

    </td>
    <td><img name="habib_contact_us_r11_c8" src="images/habib_contact_us_r11_c8.jpg" width="42" height="22" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r11_c8" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="22" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><img name="habib_contact_us_r12_c5" src="images/habib_contact_us_r12_c5.jpg" width="160" height="38" border="0" id="habib_contact_us_r12_c5" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="38" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Somewhere out there, God just killed a kitten.

Comment: down voe without saying the reason?!!

Comment: You shouldnt really trust dreamweavers view all that much as people do not view your website in it.

Comment: @Lollero thank you for your advice but now I have this problem how can I fix it. I replaced images with input fields and buttons with same size and i should not have a problem but I have!!

Comment: Dreamweaver is a paid software, why don't you fire the question to Dreamweaver support? (so every penny counts)

Comment: @ajreal I dont know for sure but i think your question/suggestion is a bit invalid as this is not technically Software related problem but a code related..

Comment: @Eyla i think your best bet is to put this site online because at least for me its really difficult to say anything cause everything looks wrong in the site as it is missing the images..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every browser renders form elements differently, some add more padding than others, so while your dreamweaver preview may look great, you have to do real-world browser testing, and if necessary apply browser-specific styles to those form elements to get them to fit your design. You should have a look at Paul Irish' HTML5 Boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/

If you want more specific help with your code, please put something up somewhere we can all see and evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve MANY of those browser css rendering differences (bascially all of them render some pieces of css code diferently mostly in small and subtle details) is the following technique:

-It is called Reset Css, here, I paste you a quick link to some of them:

**.explanation:**                http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

**.actual resetcss files:**      http://www.cssreset.com/

What Reset Css does is to "reset" the css properties to "0", this means, it tells all the browsers to erase the prefferences they have (yes, those small and subtle details that distort your css here and there in each and every browser), that means it somehow erases MANY of those uncomfortable browser css rendering differences.

It won't save you from all the browsers rendering differences, but, it sure helps, my advice is use it.

How do I use it you say? Easy, just create a new css file called "reset.css" and link it like your standard css BEFORE linking your own style.css. Another way is to just paste all that code of the resset css inside your actual css stylesheet, just on the top of it.

And btw, plugins addons etc etc, are for original african inhabitants imo.

Hope that helped.